# PropertyInfo.GetValue(obj, null) truncating strings

Tags: c#, string, reflection

This generic helper function iterates over a list of objects, accessing their public properties, and spitting out one comma delimited string per object.

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Format the properties as a list of comma delimited values, one object row per. 
    /// </summary>
    /// <typeparam name="T">Type of class contained in the List</typeparam>
    /// <param name="list">A list of objects</param>
    /// <returns>a list of strings in csv format</returns>
    public static List<string> ToCSV<T>(this IEnumerable<T> list)
        where T : class
    {
        var results = new List<string>();
        bool firstTime = true;
        foreach (var obj in list)
        {
            // header data
            if (firstTime)
            {
                firstTime = false;
                string line = String.Empty;
                foreach (PropertyInfo propertyInfo in obj.GetType().GetProperties())
                {
                    if (propertyInfo.CanRead)
                    {
                        line += propertyInfo.Name + ',';
                    }
                }
                results.Add(line);
            }
            else
            {
                string line = String.Empty;
                foreach (PropertyInfo propertyInfo in obj.GetType().GetProperties())
                {
                    if (propertyInfo.CanRead)
                    {
                        object value = propertyInfo.GetValue(obj, null);
                        if (value.GetType() == typeof(string))
                        {
                            line += "\"" + value.ToString() + "\"" + ",";
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            line += value.ToString() + ",";
                        }
                    }
                }
                results.Add(line);
            }
        }
        return results;
    }
```

One of the classes being iterated by this method has a string property, which is being truncated:

```
string BusinessItem { get; set; } // "0000", a legitimate business value
```

The problematic bit is here:

```
object value = propertyInfo.GetValue(obj, null); // value == 0
```

How do I get the value of the property as a string, not an int?

Comment: If the property is defined as a string, the result would be a string. Something else seems a bit off.

Comment: Yeah I don't buy that at all.  The number `0000` is equivalent to the number `0`, so it makes little sense to expect an arbitrary number of `0`'s.  If it is a string however then `"0"` is a lot different than `"0000"`.  I think something else is going on.

Comment: Please provide a short but *complete* program demonstrating the problem.

Comment: are you sure it is `string BusinessItem` and not `int BusinessItem`?

Comment: doesn't make any sense at all - somethings' fishy elsewhere. Make sure where the propertyInfo 'actually comes from' - so as said, a concrete example is in order.

Comment: How does the value "0000" get written to the `BusinessItem` property?  It's possible that it's being converted to an integer at some point *before it is written to* `BusinessItem`, and then when it is converted back to a string in order to set the property, the result is `"0"`.  If that's the case, then the code you've posted is not the source of the problem.

Comment: I tried an it works OK - I get "0000" as expected. Something else is going on.

Comment: As an aside, you probably want to get rid of the `else` -- as it is, your code writes the header line *instead of* the first object, rather than writing it *before* the first object.

Comment: Wild guess: you are generating a CSV file, the CSV file actually contains `0000`, but whoever program you use to read the file (Excel?) intepret that as an integere and displays `0`

Comment: What would happen if value were null?

Comment: Mimo wins. The debugger showed 0 on the object but after it was ToString() it turned out fine.

Comment: I'd like to see the 'closure' to this :)

Comment: Yes, close please moderators. Unit test before you post, embarrassing, etc.

Answer (score 3):

Consider this check:

```
if (value.GetType() == typeof(string) && (value as string).Contains(','))
```

It means that a string value will be written within quotation marks *only* if it contains a comma.

A string value of `"0000"` would be written as `0000,` to the line. If the code that reads the file checks if a value is all digits to determine if it's a number, that would be parsed as a number, not read as a string. In that case you should write *all* strings withing quotation marks, not only strings that contains a comma.

Comment: Good point. Will update in the post since it's not directly related to the question.

Comment: @DanielHarvey: what do you mean saying: "it's not related to the question?"

Comment: @DanielHarvey: Try the update in the actual code, not only in the question.

Comment: @Tigran It was provided for context and because it was a utility method I included the entire thing for others and maybe for a bit of feedback since I wrote it. Honestly, the Property.GetInfo() call was where I imagined the problem to be, but it was making no sense to me either, so I included the context so people wouldn't immediately ask.